# How to create a ASP.NET association form for a SharePoint Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm reading Professional Microsoft SharePoint 2007 Workflow Programming.

This book provides some detailed info on how SharePoint works, but not the procedures to create workflow.

I wonder how to create a ASP.NET association form (instead of InfoPath form).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at http://www.codeplex.com/wss3workflow

This project provides some templates for creating an assoication form. Even if you don't continue to use them, they might help you learn how to create them.